# CCK compound field?

Tags: entities

Given an arbitrary list of CCK fields, I would like to compound them together so that a **add more items**-click adds one more of the entire collection of fields.

Much like the [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) functionality, back-ported to CCK.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/756/cck-field-with-two-values, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-can-you-group-multiple-answer-fields

Comment: Andy is there any other solution todo this,because lot of issues i am facing in cck 3.0? [http://drupal.org/node/342904] also try this but no luck.:(

Comment: you can try and see if there's a solution to your CCK problems (maybe there are already patches on the issue queue); alternatively [you can create a custom field](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-custom-cck-fields), which is not too difficult if you're familiar with Drupal hooks and the FAPI. I don't know if [Flexifield's](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) worth bothering with, as it hasn't been touched in a year, I guess will be discontinued in favour of CCKv3.

Answer (score -2):

Follow [this link](http://poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module) and you will get you answer.

Comment: Try to include relevant information from answers in links as quoted text instead of posting only a link.  When links break, link-only answers are no longer useful.